# Wave equation- solution extincts in time

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am currently dealing with the following task:

Let $u$ be a solution to the wave equation on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty)$ with initial conditions $u(x,0)=g, u_t(x,0)=h$ where $g,h \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ are compactly supported functions. Then I want to show that there is a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $t>0$ we have

$|u(x,t)| \le C \frac{1}{t}.$

As a hint I am given that $Area(\partial B_t(x) \cap B_R(0))\le 4 \pi \min(t^2,R^2),$ but I have actually no idea where the $\frac{1}{t}$ could come from.

By the way, we have already derived the solution formula for the wave equation in $3d-$ in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in $3$D is something like$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{4\pi t^2}\int_{\partial B_t(x)}g(y)+\nabla g\cdot(y-x)+th(y)$$
Then use the fact that $g$ and $h$ are compactly supported.

Because $g$ and $h$ have compact support  we can bound the integral by a constant that depends on $g,h,\nabla g$ and $R$ where are is the largest radius of the supports of the functions, and so:

$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{4\pi t^2}\int_{\partial B_t(x)}g(y)+\nabla g\cdot(y-x)+th(y)$$
$$\le \frac{C}{t^2}(1+t)\le \frac{C}{t}.$$

Comment: functionality $s$?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, I have revised the answer

Comment: sorry I think your answer is still to general for me. (by the way, I guess $f$ is $h$?)

Comment: and also this is

Comment: I have put in more information now :)